# Passing output from a DOS command as arguments to another command?

Tags: windows, command-line

In linux, this takes one command, and passes its output (stdout) to another:

```
echo `ls`
```

What is the Windows/cmd/batch equivalent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`cmd.exe` offers a rudimentary command substitution facility using backticks, but only via the [`for` loop](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) with the `/f usebackq` option.  It's pretty brain-dead compared to what a Unix shell would do, however, as its standard behavior is to pick up only the first word of each line of output from the child and only so you can iterate over them, not so you can paste all of them at once onto the command line.  (You can adjust the behavior somewhat with the `delims` option.) Here's an example:

```
for /f usebackq %F in (`dir /w s*c`) do echo %F
```

If you want genuine Unix-style command substitution, you'll need a genuine Unix shell, e.g., either [Cygwin bash](http://cygwin.org) or my own (commercial) [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/cshell.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Example of echo output of `dir` (use single quotes, not backtick !):

```
echo off & for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir') do echo %A
```

In interactive mode, you need type `echo on` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit. If you are sure that loop only run once (i.e. output of `('xxx')` is single line), then you can direct append `echo on` in the command.

```
echo off & for /f "delims=" %A in ('set /a 0x3DE1') do net helpmsg %A & echo on
```

For unknown reason, `('set /a 0x3DE1')` can't do like `'set /a c=0x3DE1'`, even though `set /a c=0x3DE1` is works as single command.

Example of `echo hello world` from `'echo hello world'` (single quotes):

```
echo off & for /f "delims=" %A in ('echo hello world') do echo %A
```

Example of `echo hello world` from `""` (literal string):

```
echo off & for /f "delims=" %A in ("hello world") do echo %A
```

Above syntax `%A` is for interactive mode, you need double `%` in batch file, e.g. `%%A`

Take care if you do `echo %A` inside the loop, imagine if one of the line from output of command called `on`, then there are 2 problems:

[1] `echo $A` means `echo on` which will echo nothing and invisible. I can only think of comparing the `on` to handle such specific case.

[2] `echo $A` means `echo on` which will toggle back the command prompt output; You might need add extra `echo off` inside the loop., e.g.:

```
echo off & for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b') do echo %A & echo off
```

Note that above examples is far from equivalent to ``` `` ``` since it run argument line by line. You may create this batch to try to simulate `` echo `ls` `` (it loop and append all the lines into single variable separate by space and then pass as argument later):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set fls=
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b') do set fls=!fls! %%A
echo %fls%
```

-- edit : added missing spaces

Comment: You can put the `for ... echo %A` into round brackets and then append `& echo on`. This way `echo on` runs after all of the echos inside the loop.